# Removing blurred mathematical expressions into a PDF file and make it vectorized when zooming

Tags: pdf, vectorization, zooming, mathjax, blurry

I have converted an EPUB file to a PDF. Here the result of zoomed capture. :

[zoom of the PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOvdJ.png)

As you can see, the maths symbols \sum symbol and delta Kronecker are blurred.

Is there a way to fix this ? I tried to convert the PDF into PS and return to PDF ( pdf2ps and ps2pdf ) but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The symbols are obviously images, and they look to have been compressed a JPEG, which is not appropriate for that kind of image. Turning it into PostScript just means you'll get a PostScript image, so that's not going to make any difference. You need to go back to the original document and recreate the symbols using a font.

Comment: @KenS . Do you know by chance a tool or a way to keep a 100% quality converting between EPUB and PDF, especially to avoid getting these images ( surely compressed JPEG)

Comment: This is not about "vectorization" as described in the tag. Also asking for tools is generally off-topic on this site. If you have just a few formulas, I recommend just manually typesetting them, e.g. with LaTeX (I don't know of a tool which automatizes that, but there probably are some).

Comment: You could try MuPDF which is able to read ePUB and write PDF. However, if the original ePUB has the symbols as images then that won't stop them being preserved as images into the PDF. It depends on what form the symbols are in the original ePUB (assuming they are images) but provided they aren't JPEG there then it should be entirely possible to have them converted to (eg) Flate compressed data in the PDF file, rather than JPEG. Obviously they'll still be images but at least you won't get the DCT quantisation effects.